# How to change data content color of a vis js time line

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vueJS application I'm using vis.js time line to show some data,

I have integrated the vis timeline with some randomly generated data.

Following is my code for that,

```
created() {
    var now = moment().minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0);
    var groupCount = 3;
    var itemCount = 20;
    // create a data set with groups
    var names = ['John', 'Alston', 'Lee', 'Grant'];
    for (var g = 0; g < groupCount; g++) {
      this.groups.push({
        id: g,
        content: names[g]
      });
    }
    // create a dataset with items
    for (var i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
      var start = now.clone().add(Math.random() * 200, 'hours');
      var group = Math.floor(Math.random() * groupCount);
      this.items.push({
        id: i,
        group: group,
        content: 'item ' + i +
          ' <span class="" style="color:green;">(' + names[group] + ')</span>',
        start: start,
        type: 'box',
        className: 'green', //green or yellow
        title:'Testing tool tip index' + i     
      });
    }
   },
```

Then I used

```
<timeline ref="timeline"
    :items="items"
    :groups="groups"
    :options="options"
    >
    </timeline>
```

to display the time line in my vue component.

This outputs me something like follows,

[image]

Please kindly note I have added some custom css changes to change the initial look and feel of the time line.

Since this is my first experience working with vis, I want to know, how can I change the colors of those bars...

[image]

How can I assign random color to those bars instead of all green....

Answer (score 1):

I found the best way to do this was through the item's className property. So as an example, you might assign 'colour_1', 'colour_2' 'colour_3' randomly inside your 'create a dataset with items' loop.

Then provide a matching stylesheet that looks like

```css
    .colour_1 {background-color:#7fc97f; border-color:#7fc97f}
    .colour_2 {background-color:#beaed4; border-color:#beaed4}
    .colour_3 {background-color:#fdc086; border-color:#fdc086}
```

This mechanism can be extended further with additional classes applied to the container to 'switch in or out' different groups of colours depending on what you want to see.

Here's a screenshot of my (non-random) colourised timeline using this technique.

[image: Colourised Vis.Js timeline]

You /could/ alternatively use the 'template' function override to achieve a similar goal, but I found that the call to 'redraw' was a lot slower than just switching between colour palettes in CSS.